# How to Mock an object from implementation class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to mock `profileRepository.save()` from the method:

```
public ProfileEty saveProfile(){
    UserEty userEty = new UserEty();
    ProfileEty profile = new ProfileEty();
    SettingsEty settingsEty = new SettingsEty();
    CustomizeEty customizeEty = new CustomizeEty();
    profile.setUser(userEty);
    profile = profileRepository.save(profile);
    return profile;
}
```

If I try this in my Test

```
@Test
public void should_saveProfile(){
    //Given
   when(profileRepository.save(SOME_PROFILE)).thenReturn(SOME_PROFILE);
}
```

Where SOME_PROFILE is equals to:

```
public static final  ProfileEty SOME_PROFILE = new ProfileEty();
```

The `Profile` returned from the mock `profileRepository` won´t be the same as the one created in the method *`saveProfile()`*

How to make sure that I am working with the same `Profile`, or how to perform this kind of cases?

Comment: Andreahg, please comment here if you don't think your question is the same as the one I've marked it as a duplicate of, and I'll reopen.

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, I am sure that it is duplicated, but I can´t find the right source/example or keyword to see how it can be done

Comment: Did you read the answers on the question that I marked it as a duplicate of?

Comment: yes I looked at it, which post is the one describing the solution?, please

Comment: All of them. You're asking how to stub your `save` method, so that it just returns the same object that was passed into it, right?  That's exactly what Abhijeet was asking how to do.

Comment: you can probabbly do something like  
ProfileEty ety = PowerMockito.mock(ProfileEty.class)
PowerMocito.whenNew(ProfileEty .class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(ety )

Comment: @amRika alright! Thank you for the advice. I will try it out